# ROS2 Controller to send torques

Tags: motor, ros2-control, dynamixel-controller

I have been working on a self balancing robot and would really appreciate some help,
I would like to know how to send torques to motors with ros2 control, I'm using dynamixel x motors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for [dynamixel motors](https://github.com/dynamixel-community/dynamixel_hardware), but effort command interface is not implemented yet.

Do you really need torque as interface? Dynamixel seems to have current control mode, so you maybe can use the ros2_control package and extend it.

Comment: my control input after solving the state-space equation is in torque.(LQR Controller)

Comment: If the subordinate velocity controller has sufficient tracking performance (fast enough compared to your inverse pendulum), you could also formulate your LQR with having wheel acceleration as system input -> integrate the controller output to velocity -> send the velocity to your system/servos.